# Определить дополнительные параметры для Placemark

Tags: yandex-maps-api

имею такую задачу

1. есть набор адресов метро.
2. с каждым метро связан набор адресов, находящийся в заданном радиусе от метро

сами метро вывожу метками Placemark.

нужно при клике на метку метро отобразить те адреса, которые связаны с меткой - находятся внутри заданного радиуса.
сам обработчик клик прикрепляю так

```
pointBallon.events.add(['click'], function (e) {

            });
```

только как понять, на каком адресе метро кликнули?
нужно метке с метро прикрепить дополнительный параметр - идентификатор в наборе адресов метро, а потом при получении event его прочитать  - как?

Answer (score 0):

В ObjectManager у меток есть id https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__add